# Make - Override variables with something like dotenv

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Just started using Makefile and I have been make a heavily use of the capability of overriding variables through args. But sometime I have to override three or more and becomes a little annoying.

So my question is: Does Make has a built-in functionality to source a plain text file and override some variable? (like we do with dotenv libraries)

The only way I was able to accomplish this is to create an internal IF/ELSE IF/ELSE block controlled by (for example) a variable named env. It works fine but I do feel it makes to whole Makefile unnecessarily bloated.

Thanks.

Comment: Making heavy use of setting variables on the `make` command-line, especially many at a time, is a red flag for me.  Sure you *can*, but if you're relying heavily on that then I'm inclined to suspect non-idiomatic use of `make`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger But what is the alternative? I dislike the idea that there should only be one, the right school of applying `make` and - outright stupidity or abuse ignored - if one's case doesn't fall into this canon then ...what? `make` is not for you? Use CMake? That's the red flag *for me*.

Comment: @Vroomfondel, it's difficult to say what any good alternatives (using `make` or otherwise) might be when the OP has not presented any details of what they are actually doing.  In any case, the reason for concern about non-idiomatic use of `make` is that `make` idioms have grown up *for good reasons*, just like the idioms of, say, C or Python.  You won't find many over in the [python] tag objecting to comments or answers finding fault with code for being unpythonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you are looking for, but you can do something like adding this to the very end of your makefile:

```
include $(wildcard local.mk)
```

Then if the file `local.mk` exists it will be included and any variables in it will be in effect when the recipes are invoked (because they were set last).

However, this will have problems if you've already used those variables in an immediate context previously.  For example, if you have:

```
FOO = foo
MYVAR := $(FOO)

all: ; @echo $(MYVAR)

include $(wildcard local.mk)
```

where `local.mk` contains `FOO = bar`, this won't help because `MYVAR` was set to the value of `FOO` before the include file was referenced.

Another option is to put the `include` first, then be careful to always use `?=` instead of `=` so that variables preserve existing values:

```
include $(wildcard local.mk)

FOO ?= foo
MYVAR := $(FOO)

all: ; @echo $(MYVAR)
```

will work but if you forget and use `FOO = foo` then your local variables won't be in effect.

One other option, if you're worried about this, would be to use `override` in your `local.mk`; if it contains `override FOO = bar` then the second method above (`include` first) will work even if you reset `FOO` inside the makefile that setting will be ignored.  But, if you do this then you can't also override this value on the command line.

One last option, if you don't want to change your makefile, is to use `-f` on the make command line to load the local makefile.  For example, run `make -f local.mk -f Makefile` to load `local.mk` first; this is the equivalent of (and has the same behavior as) adding the `include` at the start.